# Is a "simple" proof for a regularized divergent sum considered acceptable?

Tags: divergent-series, regularization

I am not a mathematician, so I have very little experience in this area, but from what I've understood by reading online, there are ways to assign certain values to some divergent series, and there are rigorous methods for doing so.

However, sometimes there are easy ways to find what those values are through simple multiplying, subtracting equations, rearranging the terms etc. For example, in this sum:

1 + x + x^2 + x^3 +... can we just say that it equals some number S for any x, even though we know that it doesn't always converge, and then go ahead and easily prove that S = 1/(1-x) for any x ≠ 1, as long as we accept that the answers we get when x ≤ -1 or x ≥ 1 are the regularized version of that divergent series?

In other words, if we can say that a divergent series is equal to a constant and then manipulate the equation so that we find what that constant is, is that considered mathematically correct and accepted or is the value decided through much more complicated and rigorous ways?

Comment: "is that considered mathematically correct and accepted?" No. That sum is divergent: all you can say is that "IF it were convergent, then its value would be $1/(1-x)$".

Comment: There are many definitions of regularized sum, and which operations are okay when will depend on which definition you choose.

Comment: @Crostul Just because a sum is divergent doesn't mean it doesn't have a value. Hence the whole field of [divergent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series).

Answer (score 2):

The situation is nuanced. That is, the manipulations that you describe implicitly assume certain conditions and properties hold. For example, suppose that you have some operator on infinite sums, denoted by $V$, such that $V(1+x+x^2+\dots)=:S$ gives the "value" of the sum. Then you need to assume that $$V(x(1+x+x^2+\dots)) = xV(1+x+x^2+\dots)=xS, \tag{1}$$ and also $$x(1+x+x^2+\dots)=x+x^2+\dots,\tag{2}$$ and also $$S=V(1+(x+x^2+\dots))=1+V(x+x^2+\dots),\tag{3}$$ and given these you get $\; S=1+xS\;$ and finally, assuming $x\neq1,\; S=1/(1-x)$. Given all these assumptions, the reasoning is valid. Coming up with a noncontradictory $V()$ is **highly nontrivial**.

Comment: Well $V(x(1+x+x^2+\dots)) = xV(1+x+x^2+\dots)$ is the shift invariance and you don't need to assume it to obtain consistent summations. For example the zeta summation is not shift invariant (otherwise it couldn't assign a value to $1+1+1+\ldots$)

Comment: @reuns You are correct about shift invariance which was assumption (1) is not satisfied by other summation operators, but in the the context of the question it is needed.

Comment: I think the deep question here is how to prove that a summation is consistent or not. In general analytic continuation provides an easy way to ensure it is consistent (if $h_n$ is analytic and $h_n(1) = 1$ and $f(z) =\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n h_n(z) $ converges uniformly for $|z| < \epsilon$ and its analytic continuation is meromorphic for $|z| \le 1$ then it is consistent to say $S[h](\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n) = f(1)$)